# Adding textbox value, stay high value

Tags: c#, winforms

**Goal**: ***The value I enter in the first box will be written in the second box***

**Goal**: ***The second textbox will always write the highest value even if the first textbox changes***

```
private void ModuleltextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try{
        secondTxt.Text = firstTxt.Text;
        var y = int.Parse(secondTxt.Text);
        var x = int.Parse(firstTxt.Text);
                
        if (y >= x)
        {
             //??
        }
        else if(x<y)
        {
             //??
        }
    }
    catch (Exception){

    }
```

Comment: `secondTxt.Text = firstTxt.Text;` -- right when that is executed both will have the same text. That follows that `y` equals `x` (unless `int.Parse()` throws an exception) and that follows that `x < y` will never be true.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to do this in the `TextChanged()` event. What if the user types in the wrong number?  Your second box will already be changed and "committed" before the user has even hit the BackSpace key to fix their error...

Comment: I use Modbus protocol.It automatic read and write.So no user.

Comment: Do not add words like "solved" or "answered" to the title of your question. Stack Overflow has the _Accept_ button on an answer to provide that information, and changing the title to indicate that the problem has been solved is strictly against the community rules.

Comment: I know.Just im new member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the `Text` property after comparing both text boxes value like :

```
try
{
    var y = int.Parse(secondTxt.Text);
    var x = int.Parse(firstTxt.Text);
    if (y < x)
    {
      secondTxt.Text = x.ToString();         
    }
    else
    {
       secondTxt.Text = y.ToString();
       // or probably this line is not needed as y is already set in second TextBox
    }
```

if first text box value is greater it will get set in secondTextBox otherwise the secondTextBox already have highest value.

Answer (score 0):

I would think something like this would suffice?

```
private void ModuleltextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x, y;
    if (int.TryParse(firstTxt.Text, out x) && int.TryParse(secondTxt.Text, out y))
    {
        secondTxt.Text = Math.Max(x, y).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's "not working" then you haven't adequately described your setup.  I tested the code and it works.  Give more details about how the different TextBoxes get changed and how "ModuleltextBox" comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

Put this piece of code in your **textbox1 **TextChanged**** event.

```
try
{
       textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;

       int firstnum = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
       int secondnum = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

}
catch
{
                
}
```

I think your second goal is not possible if you're using a **TextChanged** event since every changes you'll made in **TextBox1** will be also made in **TextBox2**.